# How can I capture the whole web page in an Android phone while using its browser?

Tags: android, mobile, browser, screen-capture, image-capture

When I visit a web page using Android browser I can capture the visible part of the web page making a screenshot of the whole screen, but I need capture the whole web page, including the part of the web page that is outside the screen, I mean, not just the visible part of the page.

What I want is something like the option "Capture Entire Page" of Awesome Screenshot plugin. Pls, exclude all the programming method for do this, I want a already made tool easy to use for a newbie Android. The idea is allow common users reports layout bugs easily. So, what tool can I use to accomplish that?

A VALID REPLY IS SUCH TOOL NOT EXIST, but pls, put some reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Dolphin browser and Screen Cut add-on to capture full webpages on an Android phone. You do not need root access.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use any standard android method to get screenshot of entire screen (including non visible portion). But if you have root access, you can read the framebuffer to get the entire contents using [this](http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1473) method

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, are you sure that not browser plugin or whatever to allow me capture the entire web page? I really can't believe that don't exist a simple method to do so simple and useful task like capture all the web page one is looking in. Pls,confirm that you are sure that up to the date no other method exist beside what you point me out, to stop finding.

Comment: If you are using webview in your application, there is an API to capture screen http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#capturePicture()

Comment: I'm not an Android developer, I just want test my web app in Android, and in case I detect something odd in the layout report it to my XHTML/CSS/JS coder. That is why I need capture the entire webpage. Any method that not include Android native programming? and that can be executed by an Android newbie like me? Thanks again for your fast reply.

Answer (score 0):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.leavjenn.longshot

This does exactly what you want. I have tested it.

Comment: Didn't exist till Oct 2016 BTW